# Enterprise Library - validate blank spaces " "

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, enterprise-library

how do I deny blank spaces (" ") using Enterprise Library validation?

```
[StringLengthValidator(1, RangeBoundaryType.Exclusive, 100, RangeBoundaryType.Inclusive)]
```

allows them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a regular expression validator:

```
[RegexValidator("^([ ]+)$", MessageTemplate = "Invalid")]
```

Comment: Yes, that's an option. I was wondering that maybe there was an attribute for that on EntLib.